# C# .NET Core - Reference Instance Property of Class?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In C# (.NET Core), is there an easy way to get a reference to the property of a class instance, from the class itself?

What I mean by that, is if I have a class:

```
class A {
  public int SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

I'd want to get a reference to `SomeProp`, as a `PropertyInfo` or similar.

I know I can do something like `typeof(A).GetProperty("SomeProp")`, which works, but is rather verbose and isn't a constant (which means I couldn't use it in an attribute, for example).

I have a mapper which current takes two methods: `Func<TInput, TValue>` (takes in an `input` object and returns some value) and `Action<TOutput, TValue>` (takes an `output` and the return value from the previous method).

In the second method, I basically end up having a lot of these: `(o, v) => o.SomeProp = v` and I'm looking for a way to streamline this part to simply be able to provide a reference to the property itself and I handle the actual assignment behind the scenes.

Ideally, it'd be something (that isn't a string) that can be put into an attribute so I can just tag each method:

```
[AssignTo(A.SomeProp)]
public TValue GetValue(TInput in) => in.CalcValue();
```

I know I could pass in the prop name as a string, but then that causes a whole bunch of different checks to be bypassed (like checking if the property is used) and also can lead to stupid spelling mistakes.

And just for clarity, the reason to use separate, mostly single property, mapping methods instead of just direct assignment is because the real methods for getting the values are much more complex in most cases and need to support a DI-like addition of methods based on runtime criteria. The pattern I'm using is one of the cleanest for that approach.

Comment: `[AssignTo(nameof(A.SomeProp))]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent spelling mistakes/renaming issues you can use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) expression which produces the name of a variable, type, or member as the string constant and is available in C# 6 and later:

```
[AssignTo(nameof(A.SomeProp))]
public TValue GetValue(TInput in) => in.CalcValue();
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize that `A.SomeProp` actually worked inside of `nameof()`. I hadn't tried it before but knew my IDE didn't like `A.SomeInstanceProp` normally, but it was just fine with it in `nameof()`. I think this approach is probably the way to go. I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: This did indeed do the trick. Thanks a bunch. I can definitely live with an extra `nameof` function call to get typo-proof property references.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do for a compile-time constant is using the `nameof` operator. So:

```
[AssignTo(nameof(A.SomeProp))]
public TValue GetValue(TInput in) => in.CalcValue();
```

You can then access that value via reflection and use the `GetProperty` method safely, knowing that the string passed to `AssignToAttribute` really references a real object. It will count towards property usages. The downside is that it's not going to check whether the string references a real property and not a method for example.

But, as I said it's the best you can do for compile-time, as methods don't exist before they are compiled (duh) so the name used in the code is the only "reference" you can have at compile time. If you wish to have more advanced validation on these (so making sure it's a real, assignable property defined on the type in question) you'd have to write a custom Roslyn analyzer for the `AssignToAttribute`.